# How to use public imports in D

Tags: d

I am trying to replicate a namespace kind of pattern in D. I would like to have one class per file and be able to use a single `import` statement to include all classes from a group of files.

in my root folder I have moduleExp.d

```
import foo.module;
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    writeln("hello world");
    auto quakk = new Quakk();
    quakk.write();
}
```

In my foo folder I have module1.d:

```
module foo.module1;
import std.stdio;

class Quakk
{
    public string name = "thename";
    public void write()
    {
        writeln(this.name);
    }
}
```

Also in foo folder, I have module.d which I thought I could use to publicly import all my class modules into so they can be used in moduleExp.d of the root folder.

```
module foo.module;
public import foo.module1;
```

When I try to compile on Windows from the root folder with `rdmd moduleExp`, I get errors:

```
moduleExp.d(1): Error: identifier expected following package
moduleExp.d(1): Error: ';' expected
Failed: ["dmd", "-v", "-o-", "moduleExp.d", "-I."]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. if I change line 1 in module.Exp.d to `import foo.module1;` then everything works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`module` is a reserved keyword that you shouldn't use as a module name. And what you are trying to do exists as a feature in dlang called `package modules`. Look in http://dlang.org/module.html for documentation.

So basically, you have a module under the folder `foo`, its name should be `package.d`, where you publicly import the modules within foo and any other modules that you want. Example:

```
module foo; // notice the module name is used
            // for the package module and not foo.package

public import foo.module1;
public import foo.module2;
...
```

And now when you want to import the package, just write `import foo`.